# Sending file+params using webclient Spring

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How to send a file and some params at the same time using webflux webclient in Java/Kotlin? The following code did not work, it returned `500`, although I could successfully send the same data using Postman's `form-data`:

```
val multiPartRequest: MultiValueMap<String, Any> = LinkedMultiValueMap()
multiPartRequest.add("file", ByteArrayResource(myByteArray))
multiPartRequest.add("param1", "1")
multiPartRequest.add("param2", "2")
    
webClient.post()
  .uri("/upload_url")
  .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiPartRequest ))
  .retrieve()
```

Comment: Rig up a Proxy or Mock debugging Server where it will allow you to make your POST and observer the Header and Body that Postman and your code send.  Then compare.